# ANTLR maximum recursion depth exceeded error when parsing a C file with large array

Tags: python, c, parsing, antlr, antlr4

When using ANTLR a problem that I have been seeing is a max recursion depth error when testing on array’s with  large amounts of data within them.

Content of a file that produces an error looks like:

```c
const unsigned char foo[] = {
    99,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,
    0,64,0,0,0,115,248,1,0,0,100,0,90,0,100,91,
    90,1,100,92,90,2,101,2,101,1,23,0,90,3,100,4,
    100,5,132,0,90,4,100,6,100,7,132,0,90,5,100,8,
    100,9,132,0,90,6,100,10,100,11,132,0,90,7,100,12,
    100,13,132,0,90,8,100,14,100,15,132,0,90,9,100,16,
    100,17,132,0,90,10,100,18,100,19,132,0,90,11,100,20,
    100,21,132,0,90,12,100,93,100,23,100,24,132,1,90,13,
    101,14,101,13,106,15,131,1,90,16,100,25,106,17,100,26,
    100,27,131,2,100,28,23,0,90,18,101,19,106,20,101,18,
    100,27,131,2,90,21,100,29,90,22,100,30,90,23,100,31,
    103,1,90,24,100,32,103,1,90,25,101,25,4,0,90,26,
    90,27,100,94,100,33,100,34,156,1,100,35,100,36,132,3,
    90,28,100,37,100,38,132,0,90,29,100,39,100,40,132,0,
    90,30,100,41,100,42,132,0,90,31,100,43,100,44,132,0,
    90,32,100,45,100,46,132,0,90,33,100,47,100,48,132,0,
    90,34,100,95,100,49,100,50,132,1,90,35,100,96,100,51,
    100,52,132,1,90,36,100,97,100,54,100,55,132,1,90,37,
    ...
};
```

The single file contains one array with 2,432  lines of data and nothing else.
The outputted error when parsing the array is:

```
File "../antlr4/tree/Tree.py", line 147, in walk
    self.walk(listener, child)
  File "../antlr4/tree/Tree.py", line 147, in walk
    self.walk(listener, child)
  File "../antlr4/tree/Tree.py", line 145, in walk
    self.enterRule(listener, t)
  File "../antlr4/tree/Tree.py", line 159, in enterRule
    ctx.enterRule(listener)
  File "../Parser.py", line 14461, in enterRule
    listener.enterInitializerlist(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

ANTLR VERSION = 4.8

Does anyone know why this is occurring or any advice/fixes for the problem? I am using Python bindings for ANTLR4.

I am using grammar file:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

I then do:

```
java -cp ./etc/antlr-4.8-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python2 -o ./src/autogen ./grammars/C.g4 -visitor
```

Which produces the following files that I use

```
src/autogen/grammars/C.tokens
src/autogen/grammars/CLexer.py
src/autogen/grammars/CLexer.tokens
src/autogen/grammars/CListener.py
src/autogen/grammars/CParser.py
src/autogen/grammars/CVisitor.py
```

Comment: Please give a link to the grammar you are using. It's impossible to answer otherwise, i.e., we don't know if recursive rules are used for parsing the initializer.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to achieve?  Without a grammar to reference, it just looks like a bunch of uint8_t values.  Maybe you're not using the right tool for the job.

Comment: I am using C.g4 file from:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

I believe this is the latest version.

Comment: I apologize that failed to provide even sufficient information to narrow down anything. I am new to ANTLR (and grammers.) I have edited my question with more information.

Comment: I have asked this at:

https://groups.google.com/g/antlr-discussion/c/AouKqFLP-8M

which may be more appropriate place for ANTLR. I show there that by repeatedly testing w/ smaller and smaller file we were able to show that  this file when larger than 58 lines we die due to mx recursion error. I have details in that thread regarding our "ulimit -a" sizes.

Comment: initializerList is recursive, not EBNF. That's why it's blowing up.

Comment: `initializerList : designation? initializer ( ',' designation? initializer)*;` <<< do this.

Comment: Yeah, this one was closed too quickly, not giving enough time to improve/clarify. I voted to re-open, but needs 2 more votes...

Comment: I agree Bart, and I definitely prefer to answer ANTLR questions here on SO, instead of the mailing list.

Comment: This man is not lazy, he just made an oversight. It was a good question about grammar refactoring, which I spent years studying. Here or there, it is a reflection of our tendencies in this profession. But, the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments and suggestions. It appears that indeed suggested change to file C.g4 is needed in grammer for "initializerList". I have tested changes a @kaby76 suggested here and same changes suggested by a person in the googlegroups thread. This seems to fix my issues! You can see googlegorups  thread at:


https://groups.google.com/g/antlr-discussion/c/AouKqFLP-8M

I have also asked there if grammer CPP14.g4 might have similar issue. (Again, I am not a grammer person.)

Though I have not carefully measured things, parsing seemed to also go a good bit faster. Thanks.

Comment: I had previously mentioned that without this change I was reaching "max recursion depth exceeded" with just 58 lines of input. (Each line has ~20 or less numbers). After this fix the entire 2432 line file parses without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

For people who stumble upon this question: the answer is "hidden" in the comments, provided by kaby76:

> `initializerList` is recursive, not EBNF. That's why it's blowing up.
>
> Do this:
>
> ```
>  initializerList
>   : designation? initializer ( ',' designation? initializer)*
>   ;
> ```